# Lodash: Truth table with dont-cares

Tags: javascript, lodash

Say I have 4 boolean inputs (eg `[true, true, true, false]`) and for each permutation (4^2=16) I get two outputs.

so eg.

```
[true, true, true, false] -> [true, true]  
[true, true, false, true] -> [true, false
```

Creating a truth table for each of the 16 permutations is simple if you just use true or false (lets simplify to 2 inputs to shorten things):

```js
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
const myInputs = [true, true];
const truthTable = [
  {input: [false,false], output: [true, true]},
  {input: [false,true], output: [false, true]},
  {input: [true,false], output: [true, false]},
  {input: [true,true], output: [true, false]},
]

const output = truthTable.find(row=>_.isEqual(row.input, myInputs)).output
console.log(output) // [true, false]
```

But what if in a certain case an input doesn't really matter? A "dont-care" in scientific terms. The above table can be simplified to the below table because the output is the same regardless if you input `[true, true]` or `[true, false]`

```
const truthTable = [
  {input: [false,false],     output: [true, true]},
  {input: [false,true],      output: [false, true]},
  {input: [true,"dontcare"], output: [true, false]},
]
```

How do I make the truth table return the correct output if I'm not working with mere "true" or "false"? `_.isEqual` doesn't understand "dontcare"

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.isEqualWith` and write a custom equality check for `"dontcare"`

```js
const truthTable = [{
    input: [true, false, true, false],
    output: [true, true]
  },
  {
    input: [true, false, false, "dontcare"],
    output: [true, false]
  }
];

const input = [true, false, false, Math.random() > 0.5];

const isEqualWithCustomizer = (leftValue, rightValue) => {
  if (leftValue === "dontcare") return true;
};
console.log('input: ', input);
console.log('output: ',
  truthTable.find((row) =>
    _.isEqualWith(row.input, input, isEqualWithCustomizer)
  )?.output
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/threenuc/pen/ExgjJyp?editors=0012)

Comment: I tried using ramda in order to create a more declarative equivalent of the above code. Ramda doesn't have isEqualWith though - the alternative is writing eg. `const eqWithDontcares = (left, right) => left === "dontcare" ? true : R.eq(left, right);` but then you have to loop over the table yourself